# The method is called every time i open the app react native

Tags: react-native

i am extracting data from a local json and displaying it through a list, every time i exit the app without killing it or deconnect and reconnect data are duplicated (recalling the parsing method) my code looks something like this 
and if i reload or kill the app and re-open it i get the normal number of data

```
class Overview extends Component {

    constructor(props, context) {
        super(props, context);

        this.state = {
            Type: [],
        Nom: [],
        Planning: [],
        Name: [],
        FrostFreeTemperature: [],
    }
}




ParseHouse = () => {
    for (var i = 0; i < rooms.length; i++) {
        var obj_room = rooms[i];
        this.state.Name.push(obj_room.Name);
        this.state.Planning.push(obj_room.Planning);
        for (var j = 0; j < this.state.Planning.length; j++) {
            try {
                var obj_plan = this.state.Planning[i][j]
                this.state.Type.push(obj_plan.Type);
                if (this.state.Type[i].toUpperCase() == "ABSENCE") {
                    nbr_room_Absence++;
                    RoomsAbsence.push(this.state.Name[i]);
                } else if (this.state.Type[i].toUpperCase() == "COMFORT") {
                    nbr_room_Comfort++;
                    RoomsComfort.push(this.state.Name[i]);
                } else if (this.state.Type[i].toUpperCase() == "FROST FREE") {
                    nbr_room_FrostFree++;
                    RoomsFrostFree.push(this.state.Name[i]);
                }
            } catch (err) {
            }
        }
    }
}

componentWillMount(){
    this.ParseHouse();
}


_renderContentAbsence() {

    return (
        <View>
            <List
                dataArray={RoomsAbsence}
                  renderRow={(roomAb) =>
                      <ListItem>
                          <Text>{roomAb}</Text>
                      </ListItem>
                  }>
            </List>
        </View>
    );
}

render(){
     return(
        <ScrollView style={styles.scroll}>
            <Navbar/>
            <StatusBar
                backgroundColor="#1769AC"
                barStyle="light-content"
            />



            <Accordion
                sections={Absence}
                renderHeader={this._renderHeaderAbsence}
                renderContent={this._renderContentAbsence}>
            </Accordion>



        </ScrollView>
        );
    }
}
```

Is there any solution for this and thank you

Comment: componentWillMount does not get called a second time if you put your app in the background and open again on android. So it is probably the Accordion's fault. What are you using for that?

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering, i am using react-native-collapsible/Accordion

Comment: As I understand you are displaying Lists in an Accordion. Which data is doubling, the content of the list or the Accordion parts? And where does the variable Absence used in `sections={Absence}
` get value?

Comment: Duplicated datas are the lists inside the accordion the Absence value is a constant :  const Absence = [
    {
        title: 'Absence'
    }
];

Comment: Unfortunately I don't see the problem. What I would do is to put a breakpoint at the start of ParseHouse and check the callstack to find out what is calling it.